# HALF of a transaction reverted

Tags: solidity, calldata, reentrant-attacks

I am reading an interesting [honeypot](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/7x5rwr/tricked_by_a_honeypot_contract_or_beaten_by/du6bo6u/?newUser=true) posted years ago. But I was confused by how [the honeypot contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf8681dad1ce4f1f414fb07fc07f81a3a82e91d8f) is implemented.
More specifically, take [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xed5eaf959224dff10fb705e16af81017374f3f3856ada926571aa9f8ef8e0b63) as an example. As we can see, during this transaction:

```
TRANSFER  1 Ether From 0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0 To  0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639
TRANSFER  2 Ethers From 0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639 To  0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0
```

However, after the transaction, the balance of `0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639` increased by 1 ether. It looks like the honeypot contract reverted **half** of the transaction.

There were discussions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/7x5rwr/tricked_by_a_honeypot_contract_or_beaten_by/du6bo6u/?newUser=true).

I also tried `revert()` `assert()` in my `TransferLog.AddMessage`. But neither of them worked: the whole transaction reverted and no ether was sent to the contract.

Any hints/help will be appriciated.

Comment: As I see it here 

CONTRACT:0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0 first tried to transfer 1ETH to 0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639  and that went well.

But then  

CONTRACT:0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0 tried to send 2ETH to itself from the other account, and that ofcourse failed.

Comment: I do not think so, that's how the honeypot contract works. Please see the contract solidity code for more:  https://etherscan.io/address/0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639#code

And here is a discussion: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/7x5rwr/tricked_by_a_honeypot_contract_or_beaten_by/

Answer (score 2):

No, a transaction is fully atomic: either everything in it fails, or everything succeeds.

There are minor exceptions to this rule in the sense of `try-catch` statements, which allow the calling contract to allow the called external contract to revert, without reverting the calling contract as well. So in this case the called contract's state changes are reverted, but the caller contract continues executing (and the transaction as a whole may still succeed). More details about try-catch: https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/01/29/solidity-0.6-try-catch/

Looking at the transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xed5eaf959224dff10fb705e16af81017374f3f3856ada926571aa9f8ef8e0b63 , it would appear to go like this:

1. 0xe0b4789d1cb42f0ee149bfbc12f016dbd55db33b sends 1 Eth to 0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0 (during the function call)
2. 0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0 sends 1 Eth to 0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639
3. 0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639 sends 1 Eth to 0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0
4. 0x95d34980095380851902ccd9a1fb4c813c2cb639 sends 1 Eth to 0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0

With this logic, 0x6f49baef279f8c40d7479f5be6a9bbf5fc607af0 should end up with 2 Eth more. But if you look at the "State" tab, you notice that the situation is quite different.

This is probably some funny way how Etherscan displays some information. Or maybe there is even a bug in their logic. Just remember that Etherscan is an arbitrary third-party service, which is centralized and shouldn't be trusted blindly.

So, no, I don't understand how Etherscan's data should be read.

Comment: Thanks， that's how I understand it.

Could you please take a look at the example transaction I posted(in the description). And see if you can find the trick/magic. [It does look like HALF of the transaction reverted].

If you read the contract source code, `try/catch`/`low-level call` is not the case.

Comment: Edited to add more info

Comment: I do not think it etherscan's problem.

Not just etherscan, if you read the tx from `other 3rd party services`, it is the same. Example:

https://tx.blocksecteam.com/

You can read the "Account Balance" on it.